# How can I tell if the main thread has gone away?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm performing a few steps from a background thread, updating the view on the completion of each using:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgress) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

The problem is if the user dismisses this view. The background thread continues to run, and crashes the app when it gets to one of these actions. How can I tell if the thread has gone away?

Comment: Have you tried using @try - @catch?

Comment: Typically your program exits...

Comment: @H2CO3 It seems that that particular thread does not though, or those particular selectors anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Do you intend run method `updateProgress` in Main thread or Background thread? This is simple trick to check. For the full proof you should use `NSOperationQueue` instead of `performSelector`

synthesize this `BOOL` in your viewController

```
BOOL isBackgroundThreadStop;
```

initialize to `NO` somewhere relevant

```
self.isBackgroundThreadStop = NO;
```

When user pressed button dismiss the view:

```
-(void)dismissView
{   
    self.isBackgroundThreadStop = YES;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerWhatEver];
}
```

So in your method

```
-(void)updateProgress
{
    if(!self.isBackgroundThreadStop){
    //run program if background thread not stop
    //it won't run if isBackgroundThreadStop is set to YES
    }
}
```